# what is the advantages of nested classes if not getting a collection of them?

Tags: class, oop, poco

I have seen some examples that go like this:

```
public class Customer
{
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
 public Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
 public string Street { get; set; }
 public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And I can't still figure out what advantages has over the following:

```
public class Customer
{
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
 public string Street { get; set; }
 public string City { get; set; } 
}
```

Any ideas about it?

Cheers.

Comment: Read about database normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you showed is not a nested class, but a property making use of another class through composition.

> The main advantage in your example is that the `Address` is a separate
>   entity (refactored out) and may be used to indicate different classifications of
>   address for a given `Customer` e.g a Customer may have a `Home
>   Address`, a `Business Address` and a `Corporate Address` which all
>   will be of type `Address` class.

Achieving above type of classification without having a separate `Address` class would be difficult otherwise and that's the one reason `Address` is taken out as a separate class.

As an illustration, your `Customer` class can be modified as below to show one of the advantages:

```
public class Customer
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
     public Address BusinessAddress { get; set; }
     public Address CorporateAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Now, as per above example if your `Address` entity later requires `ZipCode` also, then you don't need to add 3 zipcodes (1 for Home, 1 for Business and 1 for Corporate); you just add the `ZipCode` property to the `Address` class and the 3 properties in `Customer` class make use of the new property without *modifying* the `Customer` class.

Answer (score 2):

Your class is not nested, it just uses composition. Composition is composing a class from one or more other classes. It's advantage is reuse of course.

You can use your `Address` class in another class or method and you also encapsulate all the logic and data that must be in the `Address` class.

If you want nested classes then you can write it as:

```
public class Apple
{
    public int Mass;
    public Worm MyWorm;

    public class Worm
    {
         public string Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what a nested class is.